# Does LIKE operator still takes advantage of bucketing in Hive?

Tags: hive

If I have a bucketing defined on a certain column colA, if I fire the following query, will it still take advantage of the bucketing?

```
select * from mytable where colA like '%somestring';
```

If not, does it explicitly need equality condition for it to take advantage of bucketing? like this:-

```
select * from mytable where colA = 'somestring';
```

Answer (score 0):

Bucket pruning happens with one of the following conditions - 
Equals to (=)
In condition (where data in (...))
And and or conditions based on the above.
You can explain plan and see the number of rows it fetched.

Comment: it shows the same number of records fetched , but it means it doesn't matter if I do LIKE or equality ? That sort of sounds like counter intuitive -- because LIKE will need to do lot more work I believe.

Comment: Did you load the data in sorted order? `set hive.enforce.sorting=true;`

Comment: Yes tried with that too , numbers are still the same